# Dynamic Query Different Behavior While Trigger Creation

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016, dynamicquery

Below is part of my code that dynamically creates `Trigger`. The problem I am facing here is when I run this scrip using `Agent Job`, the `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` within the trigger is set to `OFF` by default. But when I run it by myself as adhoc query, the trigger ends up with `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` option. That's the desired behavior.

```
            SET @cmd3 = N'EXEC ' + @dbName + '..sp_executesql N''
                    CREATE TRIGGER TRG_LogAudit ON DATABASE
                        FOR 
                            -- Procedures
                            CREATE_PROCEDURE, ALTER_PROCEDURE, DROP_PROCEDURE,

                            -- Tables
                            CREATE_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE, DROP_TABLE,

                            -- Views
                            CREATE_VIEW, ALTER_VIEW, DROP_VIEW,

                            -- Functions
                            CREATE_FUNCTION, ALTER_FUNCTION, DROP_FUNCTION,

                            -- Schemas
                            CREATE_SCHEMA, ALTER_SCHEMA, DROP_SCHEMA,

                            -- Triggers
                            CREATE_TRIGGER, ALTER_TRIGGER, DROP_TRIGGER,

                            -- Others
                            RENAME
                    AS
                        BEGIN
                            SET NOCOUNT ON;
                            DECLARE @EventData XML = EVENTDATA();

                            DECLARE @ip VARCHAR(32) = ( SELECT  client_net_address
                                                        FROM    sys.dm_exec_connections
                                                        WHERE   session_id = @@SPID
                                                      );

                            INSERT  meta.LogAudit
                                    (EventType
                                    ,EventDDL
                                    ,EventXML
                                    ,DatabaseName
                                    ,SchemaName
                                    ,ObjectName
                                    ,HostName
                                    ,IPAddress
                                    ,ProgramName
                                    ,LoginName
                                    )
                                    SELECT  @EventData.value(''''(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]'''', ''''NVARCHAR(100)'''')
                                           ,@EventData.value(''''(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]'''', ''''NVARCHAR(MAX)'''')
                                           ,@EventData
                                           ,DB_NAME()
                                           ,@EventData.value(''''(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]'''', ''''NVARCHAR(255)'''')
                                           ,@EventData.value(''''(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]'''', ''''NVARCHAR(255)'''')
                                           ,HOST_NAME()
                                           ,@ip
                                           ,PROGRAM_NAME()
                                           ,SUSER_SNAME();
                        END;
    ''';
....
```

How to modify my script in order to make sure trigger would always have `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` option set to `ON`? I have tried some nested `EXEC` commands but with not success.

Comment: Have you tried just adding `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` where needed in the script?

Comment: Yes. But the problem here is that the "CREATE TRIGGER" must be first statement in the query so I cannot just put it there.